# Where did ı go wrong?I got a error that 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, ı want to write a function that takes a list of 5 numbers input by the user and returns the largest number in this list. Print that largest number. Function structure should be: `int findLargestNum(list)`

```
listabc = input("type 5 numbers: ").split

def findLargestNum(a):
    a.sort()
    return a[-1]
print("the largest num is : ",findLargestNum(listabc))
```

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis to the `.sort()` function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot `split` is not an **attribute** of a list, it is its **method**. Therefore, you need to correct the first line in favour of `listabc = input("type 5 numbers: ").split()`.